# SQL Query to select the COUNT from another SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm having a little trouble making an SQL SERVER 2000 query. Here is my scenario:

- I have a table called **Folders**  with 3 columns: **pk_folderID**, **folderName** and **fk_userID**.
- Also, I have another table called **FolderMedia**  which stores what media (whatever) belong to a certain folder. There are 2 columns: **fk_folderID**, **fk_media**.
- And the last, I have a table called **Media** which stores some media details. It has a primary key **pk_media** and among other columns, it has a **MediaType** column which tells the type of that media: image or video.

Now, I would like a query that does the following:

Select all folders that belong to a certain **fk_userID**, and then also get the number of media in that folder. I've seen a query like this here on StackOverflow, but I didn't manage to upgrade it to get 2 counts of media (based on their type)

Basically, get the folder details (name, etc) for all folders that belong to a user(fk_userID) and also, for each folder get the number of images and videos in it (as separate values).

The select would basically return: 
folderName, count(images in folder), count(videos in folder), other folder details.

One obvious solution would be to just get all folders and then manually calculate the number of images/videos in them... but I would first like to try with a query.

Thank you,

Comment: This is an interesting question, which may have more than one solution, depending on the approach. There's just one thing. Although it is not really difficult to make up a name for the media type column, yet, since it is important for the resulting query, you should have provided the name yourself, just like you did for other important columns.

Comment: Ok, I will just add the column name now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically something like this:

```
SELECT
  f.pk_folderID,
  f.folderName,
  VideoCount = COUNT(CASE m.MediaType WHEN 'Video' THEN 1 END),
  ImageCount = COUNT(CASE m.MediaType WHEN 'Image' THEN 1 END)
FROM Folder f
  LEFT JOIN FolderMedia fm ON f.pk_folderID = fm.fk_folderID
  LEFT JOIN Media m ON fm.fk_media = m.pk_media
WHERE f.fk_userID = @UserID
GROUP BY
  f.pk_folderID,
  f.folderName
```

---

**UPDATE** (based on the additional request):

To include a sort of `TOP 1 Media.Name` into the result set, the above query could be changed like this:

```
SELECT
  f.pk_folderID,
  f.folderName,
  VideoCount = COUNT(CASE m.MediaType WHEN 'Video' THEN 1 END),
  ImageCount = COUNT(CASE m.MediaType WHEN 'Image' THEN 1 END),
  MediaName  = MAX(CASE fm.timestamp WHEN t.timestamp THEN m.Name END)
FROM Folder f
  LEFT JOIN FolderMedia fm ON f.pk_folderID = fm.fk_folderID
  LEFT JOIN Media m ON fm.fk_media = m.pk_media
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      fk_folderID,
      timestamp = MIN(timestamp)
    FROM FolderMedia
    GROUP BY fk_folderID
  ) t ON fm.fk_folderID = t.fk_folderID AND fm.timestamp = t.timestamp
WHERE f.fk_userID = @UserID
GROUP BY
  f.pk_folderID,
  f.folderName
```

In cases where minimal `FolderMedia.timestamp` values are not unique within their folders, the ultimate value of the corresponding `Media.Name` will be decided by its alphabetical sorting. In particular, the above query selects the last one of the set (with `MAX()`).

Comment: Ok. What if I would also like to select the `TOP 1 Media.Filename` for each folder, when the media in the folder is ordered by some criteria (like `FolderMedia.timestamp DESC`). Basically, get the filename for the last media added to each folder. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrei Stanescu: I hope I understood your request correctly and the updated query should do what you want. If it doesn't, though, I would really recommend you to post a new question asking about how to extend the former solution so as to include one media name. Someone might come up with a better idea about solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Get all data you need from `Folders` table left join it with `FolderMedia` and `Media`
use `sum` with `case` inside to count all videos and images.

`SUM(CASE WHEN mediaTypeId = videoId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as videoCount`

Answer (score 0):

//select folderName ,count(case when Folders.pk_folderID then 1 else null end)

```
count(SELECT FolderMedia.fk_media from FolderMedia JOIN Media on fk_media=pk_media where image is not null) as nrImg
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query with some example data. Hope it helps.

```
declare @Folders table (pk_folderID int, folderName varchar(32), fk_userID int)
declare @Media table (pk_media int, name varchar(50), type varchar(32))
declare @FolderMedia table (fk_folderID int, fk_media int)

insert into @Folders values (1, 'Folder1', 1000)
insert into @Folders values (2, 'Folder2', 1000)
insert into @Folders values (3, 'Folder1', 2000)
insert into @Folders values (4, 'Folder1', 2000)

insert into @Media values (1, 'graph.jpg', 'image')
insert into @Media values (2, 'timer.jpg', 'image')
insert into @Media values (3, 'timer1.jpg', 'image')
insert into @Media values (4, 'harry_potter.mpeg', 'video')
insert into @Media values (5, 'harry_potter1.mpeg', 'video')
insert into @Media values (6, 'harry_potter2.mpeg', 'video')

insert into @FolderMedia values (1, 1)
insert into @FolderMedia values (1, 3)
insert into @FolderMedia values (1, 6)
insert into @FolderMedia values (2, 2)
insert into @FolderMedia values (2, 4)

select folderName, fk_userID, imageData.imgCount, videoData.videoCount from 
@Folders
left outer join
(
    select fk_folderID, COUNT(*) as imgCount
    from @FolderMedia
    inner join @Media 
    on fk_media = pk_media
    and type = 'image'
    group by fk_folderID
) as imageData
on imageData.fk_folderID = pk_folderID
left outer join
(
    select fk_folderID, COUNT(*) as videoCount
    from @FolderMedia
    inner join @Media 
    on fk_media = pk_media
    and type = 'video'
    group by fk_folderID
) as videoData
on videoData.fk_folderID = pk_folderID
where fk_userID = 1000
```